# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'

Tags: python, floating-point, string-conversion, valueerror

I have a list of strings (CD_cent) like this:

```
2.374 2.559 1.204
```

and I want to multiply these numbers with a float number.
For this I try to convert the list of strings to a list of floats for example with:

```
CD_cent2=[float(x) for x in CD_cent]
```

But I always get the error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'`. I guess this means, that it can't convert the dot to a float (?!) But how could I fix this? Why doesn't it recognize the dot?

Comment: Is `CD_cent == "2.374 2.559 1.204"`? If so, `for x in CD_cent` will iterate over characters, ie, `x = 2`, `x = '.'`, `x = 3`, etc. That's why it's complaining, because `'.' ` can't be converted to float.

Comment: yes the command `print(CD_cent)` gives me `'2.374 2.559 1.204'`

Comment: oh ok... so do you have an idea how i could fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to `split` each string as the string has multiple values:

```
your_str = "2.374 2.559 1.204"

floats = [float(x) for x in your_str.split(' ')]
```

Having a list you can do something like this:

```
li = [...]
floats = []

for s in li:
    floats.extend([float(x) for x in s.split(' ')])
```

In your exact situation you have a single string `CD_cent = 2.374 2.559 1.204`, so you can just:

```
floats = [float(x) for x in CD_cent.split(' ')]
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it. But I would explicitly add `str.split(" ")` to make it clear how the string should be split.

Comment: @darksky, yes, sure, forgot to add `' '`. Updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: Or even just `split()` without any arguments, so that this works with any kind of whitespace delimiter

Comment: Thanks guys! That was what i needed :)

Comment: Bleh, don't name strings `str`.  `str` is the string class/constructor, and now you shadowed it.

Comment: @Kevin, yes, it's a bad SO habit. Thanks for your edit

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your line with the provided data everything worked fine and all the strings converted to floats without error. The error indicates that somewhere in your `CD_cent` there is a single DOT `.` that really can't be converted to float.

To try to solve this do:

```
CD_cent2=[float(x) for x in CD_cent if x != '.']
```

And if that doesn't work because of other strings you will have to `try...except` like this:

```
CD_cent2 = []
for x in CD_cent:
    try:
        CD_cent2.append(float(x))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

All of that is because I assume `CD_cent` is not just a long string like `'2.374 2.559 1.204'` but it is a list like `[2.374,2.559,1.204]`. If that is not the case than you should `split` the line like this

```
CD_cent2=[float(x) for x in CD_cent.split()]
```