# Changing Data Type

Tags: python, csv, object, jupyter-notebook, type-conversion

I am trying to convert an object column in a csv to a float but I keep getting an error. If someone can steer me in the right direction that would be great. Below is the code I used:

```
df['Price'] = df.Price.astype(float)

df.dtypes
```

Error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '13,000'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046281/valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float)

Comment: Can you provide more details such as data stored in df?

Answer (score 1):

As you are speaking of a csv, it would be better to have `read_csv` to to the conversion with `read_csv(..., decimal=',')`. If for any reason it is not possible, a simple way is to replace the commas with dots:

```
df['Price'] = df.Price.str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue occurs because your numbers contain a comma separator for thousands.
Maybe this is helpful:

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' ) 
locale.atof(df['Price'])
```